# Solve $ h(t) = \int_{0}^{t} e^{ - (\eta + \mu) s } \{\mu + \eta \, \, h(t-s)^2 \} ds. $

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, recursion

Suppose that $h(t) : [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ satisfies,
$$
 h(t) = \int_{0}^{t} e^{  - (\eta + \mu) s   } \{\mu + \eta  \, \, h(t-s)^2 \} ds,
$$
where $\eta, \mu \geq 0$.
I need to prove  that, if  $\mu \neq \eta$, then,
$$
 h(t) = \frac{ \eta e^{\eta t}    - \eta e^{  \mu t }  }{    \eta e^{\eta t} -   \mu e^{\mu t} }.
 $$
Would you have some hint?

Answer (score 1):

This is hint in the form of a suggestion, as one way to approach the problem. Since you don't have to derive the expression for $h(t)$, you could first check that it satisfies the integral equation, and second show that the integral equation has a unique solution. One way to show uniqueness would be to derive from the integral equation, an ordinary differential equation satisfied by $h$, since we have a standard uniqueness theorem for ode's.